# eclipse highlights an error but ndk compiles a project

Tags: c++, eclipse, android-ndk, highlight

I compile a native C++ project under Eclipse Juno & android-ndk-r8d

I am confused by the situation, when android-ndk-r8d compiles my project with a few minor warnings (not errors!) and creates an executable file, despite the highlighting of various errors (unresolved headers, unknown functions and others...) by eclipse))) Any suggests?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Sounds like Eclipse CDT hasn't been set-up correctly so it can find those header files...

Comment: that's not all that uncommon. Sometimes rebuilding the index for that project might solve it, for example

Comment: I get that all the time, even with a fresh install of Eclipse, CDT, ADT, NDK. Sometimes it restricts me from running my built app (so annoying...) but what I do is go to the problems tab and delete + debug again so in the 3-5s it takes to rescan the project and throw the errors again it has enough time to package the app and then launch it.